# Crosswalk error on android build in cordova project

Tags: android, cordova, maven, phonegap-build

I have Cordova based application based on backbone js.

But when I tried to create android build then it will give me following error.

```
[exec] > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_armv7DebugApkCopy'.
[exec]    > Could not resolve org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library:23+.
[exec]      Required by:
[exec]          :android:unspecified
[exec]       > Could not resolve org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library:23+.
[exec]          > Failed to list versions for org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library.
[exec]             > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://download.01.org/crosswalk/releases/crosswalk/android/maven2/org/xwalk/xwalk_core_library/maven-metadata.xml.
[exec]                > Could not GET 'https://download.01.org/crosswalk/releases/crosswalk/android/maven2/org/xwalk/xwalk_core_library/maven-metadata.xml'. 
                        Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
```

It appears to be trying to fetch some data from this url: https://download.01.org/crosswalk/releases/crosswalk/android/maven2/org/xwalk/xwalk_core_library/maven-metadata.xml19

Which at this moment in time is throwing a 403. I tried building it with internet access turned off in case this is only necessary if it's available, but it tries and fails (obviously) to get it.

Is this build dependent on an active internet connection and a remote xml file that may or may not be available?

I have also tested with [a solution from the ionic forum](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/crosswalk-error-on-android-build/77774), and a white screen appears after installing the build on the device.

Comment: same here cannot build..so far tried to update / install all android sdk stuff..nothing seems to help..created also a cordova project from scratch added crosswalk but no build

Comment: https://twitter.com/xwalk_project/with_replies  ..it looks they are aware and working on it

Comment: okay thank you so the issue from there side

Comment: I'm getting the same error.

Comment: me too.. Wait for there website to be up. Build needs to have access there.

Comment: Issue get resolved https://twitter.com/xwalk_project/status/826104321276248064

Comment: i am actually facing the issue right now the same can anyone guide me on this

Comment: https://crosswalk-project.org/jira/browse/XWALK-7553

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image]

Server is down for maintenance!

https://crosswalk-project.org/jira/browse/XWALK-403

Comment: Hey thanks bro you save my day =D

Comment: @Muhammad thank you.

Comment: Now issue get resolved.

Comment: have a happy coding :)